# Allow nil values on string column but not empty string on Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a migration that creates a string column. I want to allow my column to be nil, but I don't want it to have empty string values (`''`). Is there anything that I can include in the migration or model to validate that if not nil, then the string is not empty?

Comment: Please, show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about blank string? (ie: a string like `"       "` with all white spaces?)

I'm not sure if there's something at DB level, but for the activerecord model I would use something like:

```
validates :my_column, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

This validation will check that the string is not empty (it will prevent the model for being saved if the string is `"    "` too, not just `""`)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence

---

If you only want to exclude `""` but allow `" "`, then I would use something like

```
validates :my_column, length: {minimum: 1}, allow_nil: true
```

Note the difference between using a minimum length (uses `length` to trigger the validation error) instead of presence (uses the `blank?` method to trigger the validation error)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length (check the tip on the guide about adding a custom message for `minimum: 1` since the default error message is plural)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validator on your model:

```
validate :validate_not_empty_string

def validate_not_empty_string
  errors.add(:base, "String cannot be empty") if my_column == ""
end
```

This should not fire for nil, since `nil != ""`.

I would handle this at the model rather than in the migration.

Comment: `.blank?` returns true or false so comparison with "" will not give desired results.

Comment: Whoops - I changed plans mid-writing, and forgot to pull out the ".blank?".  I've fixed that now.